# Websocket connection failed on aws if it is in background process

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, websocket, ws

I have a *websocket programme* in `nodejs` and have uploaded on aws EC2 
I am using `nohup node server.js`  command to run background process and it is connecting fine
But after few hour background process getting fail and I am not able to connect my socket again

I have already used `PING/PONG` in order to keep Websockets alive

I am using aws 12 month of free trial

Comment: Is the websocket crashing on the actual server or are you losing the connection from the client?

Comment: No it is not crashing, It is running perfectly on local as well as on server but I think Server getting stoped after few hour
Please check below step How I am getting problem in connecting websocket

1. Started websocket server
2. Tried to connect from client and it get connected
3.   After successful connection every function is working 

4. After few hour I tried connect from client it is showing an alert undefined

I am using aws server 1 year free trial @otw